Number of extensions of an embedding into an algebraic closed field is not determined by the original embedding.
I've been really struggling with grasping this concept, and I think I have some fundamental issue with grasping this concept:

Definition: Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of fields, and let $\varphi: K \hookrightarrow \Omega $ be an embedding of $K$ into some algebraic closed field $\Omega$. We denote: $$i_\varphi(L/K)= \# \{\widehat{\varphi}:L\hookrightarrow\Omega\big|\widehat{\varphi}|_K=\varphi\}$$
Lemma: If $L=K(\alpha)$ is a finite simple extension, then $i_\varphi(L/K)$ equals the number of distinct roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, $m_\alpha \in K[x]$.
Theorem: Let $\varphi:K\hookrightarrow\Omega$ be an embedding into an algebraic closed field $\Omega$. Then for any finite extension of fields $L/K$, $i_\varphi(L/K) \ge1$, and this number is not dependent on $\Omega$ or $\varphi$ (so we can denote it $i(L/K)$).

The lemma is used in order to prove the theorem, by using induction on $[L:K]$.
What I don't understand is how can $i_\varphi(L/K)$ not be determined by $\varphi$ and $\Omega$ if it's defined by the number of extensions of a given embedding $\varphi$ into a given algebraic closed field $\Omega$?

What they mean is that if you pick any other algebraically closed field $\Omega'$ and any other embedding $\varphi' : K \hookrightarrow \Omega'$, you get the same number.
